# What is the exact purpose of expiring a password reset link?

Tags: http

If someone has access to the link, they most likely have access to the user's email account to which the email with the link was sent and can  request (and read) a new password reset link email at will.

Comment: Because it doesn't leave it lying around for someone else to use later.

Comment: This question is probably better suited at [security.se] as it has nothing to do with programming. (But be sure to read their [tour](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) first.)